# Getting chart.js to work with Django and Apache

Tags: javascript, json, django, jsonp, chart.js

I have the following setup. I've a simple `index.html` being served through apache. It looks like the following.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'> <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF8"> <head> <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.4/Chart.min.js"></script> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> </head> <body> <canvas id="myChart"></canvas> <script language="JavaScript" src="/customcharts.js"> </script> </body> </html>
```

All the above does is to try and place a line chart on the browser. It uses `chart.js`. To accomplish this the `customcharts.js` tries to connect to a locally running `django` server. The above html is being served through apache running on port 8080 while django runs on port 8090.

the `customcharts.js` looks as follows

```
function renderChart(data){
    console.log(data)
    console.log(data.labels)
    defaultLabels = data.labels
    defaultData = data.defaultData
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels: defaultLabels,
        datasets: [{
        lineTension: 0,
        label: 'Activity Profile',
        data: defaultData,
        }]
    }
    })
}

var endpoint = 'http://localhost:8090/polls/alice/'
var defaultData = []
var defaultLabels = []

$.ajax({
    url: endpoint,
    dataType: "JSONP",
    success: renderChart,
    method: 'GET'
}
);
```

Further, my `django` view is

```
def json_response(func):
    """
    A decorator thats takes a view response and turns it
    into json. If a callback is added through GET or POST
    the response is JSONP.
    """
    def decorator(request, *args, **kwargs):
        objects = func(request, *args, **kwargs)
        if isinstance(objects, HttpResponse):
            return objects
        try:
            data = simplejson.dumps(objects)
            if 'callback' in request.REQUEST:
                # a jsonp response!
                data = '%s(%s);' % (request.REQUEST['callback'], data)
                return HttpResponse(data, "text/javascript")
        except:
            data = simplejson.dumps(str(objects))
        return HttpResponse(data, "application/json")
    return decorator

epoch = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(0)

r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
threat_list = ['date', 'categories', 'mix']

@json_response
def index(request, uid):
    print uid
    uid = uid.rstrip('/')
    _key = uid
    retjsondict = {}
    input_keys = [_key + ':' + x for x in threat_list]
    k = input_keys[0]
    retdict = {}
    if r.exists(k):
        retvalue = r.get(k).strip('"')
        xdata_dt = [x.split(':')[0] for x in retvalue.split(' ')]
        ydata_dt = [x.split(':')[1].rstrip(',') for x in retvalue.split(' ')]
        retdict['defaultLabels'] = xdata_dt
        retdict['defaultData'] = ydata_dt
    print retdict
    return JsonResponse(retdict)
```

the `index` is the real view and the `json_response` is a decorator.

However, when I try and view it on a browser using  `http://localhost` I get the following error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8090/polls/alice/. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Could someone point to me what I'm doing off? 
Any help/pointers appreciated.

Comment: is `customcharts.js` a static resource?

Comment: yes its a static resource

Answer (score 1):

If `customcharts.js` is within the `static/yourapp` you need to load your script as follows:

```
<script src="{% static 'yourapp/customcharts.js' %}"></script>
```

Don't forget to call `{% load staticfiles %}`

Then, a static resource can't call a view, you need to get the json data in the view and then pass it to the javascript function.

Your template should look as follows:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'> 
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF8">
    <head> 
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.4/Chart.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script language="JavaScript" src="{% static 'yourapp/customcharts.js' %}"> </script>
        <script language="JavaScript">
            $.getJSON("{% url 'index' %}", function(data) {  // 'index' is the name of the view in your urls.py
                renderChart(data);
            });
        </script>
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>  
    </body> 
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll check this out and get back

Comment: maybe you will need to put the `$.getJSON` function inside `document.ready`

Comment: When I tried it I get the following error Reverse for 'index' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['polls/(.*)polls/(.*)$', 'polls/(.*)$']   I guess I've to specify the parameter "alice" inside the "url index" thing somehow. Not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

Use 'polls' instead of 'index'

Comment: Getting close. This appears to simply render my json into the browser. The "renderChart" isn't being called I think.  Output on the browser is {"defaultLabels": ["2017-01-01", "2017-01-02", "2017-01-03", "2017-01-04", "2017-01-05", "2017-01-06", "2017-01-07"], "defaultData": ["12", "8", "4", "9", "18", "1", "4"]} as plain text

Comment: use `jquery.parseJson()`: `renderChart(jquery.parseJson(data));`